How can I put a letter immediately after inline code in org-mode?
In markdown, I can write `foo`s to get foos. How do I do the same in Org Mode? ~foo~s doesn't do it and ~foo~ s adds a space.

It seems unnatural, but a zero-width space works. Type ~foo~s then, just before the s, use C-x 8 RET and choose 200B.

That is the recommended solution to such problems. Another possibility  is to muck around with org-emphasis-regexp-components but it is error-prone, it tends to have wide ramifications and it is frowned upon by the devs - they would rather have the variable disappear.

@NickD That's a shame. Doesn't it confuse LaTeX-based exports?

I don't know - does it?

@NickD I occasionally see error messages about LaTeX not recognising the 200B character.

Are you using xelatex or lualatex? If you are using pdflatex there might be problems with Unicode in general.

@NickD Pretty sure it's pdflatex.

See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366019/unicode-with-pdflatex

@NickD Do you recommend against pdflatex? I'm happy to make the change, but I've never had any reasons to even think about it.

Yes, I think current best practice requires xetex or luatex exactly because they know about Unicode. pdftex is an 8-bit engine and its Unicode support is spotty and somewhat inconsistent.
